# После нескольких переключений между табами приложение работает намного медленее

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Вот в этом и есть проблема. У меня 2 таба и если сравнительно быстро переключаюсь между ними 2 - 5 раз то все ок, потом еще пару раз и заметно медленнее происходит переключение, потом еще раз два и вообще на 3-4 секунды зывисает между переключениями...

Единственное, что могу предположить это то что при переключении в бэке запускаются процессы и чем больше переключений тем больше процессов и таким образом и происходит зависание.

Но у меня не запускаются процессы...

У меня один таб пустой, а на втором `RecyclerView` который вытаскивает из синглтона данные... Но я не думаю, что вытащить данные так загружает девайс...

Вот сам код

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
    contentFrameRecycler = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contentFrameRecycler);
    contentFrameFree = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contentFrameFree);

    contentFrameFree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    contentFrameRecycler.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    rvFriends = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvFriends);

    if (getActivity() != null) {
        activityFriendsInbox = (ActivityFriendsInbox) getActivity();
    }

    if (!isViewShown) {
        fetchContacts();
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

тут нужный метод это `fetchContacts();`

При загрузке фрагмента он вызывается

Вот он

```
private void fetchContacts() {
    boolean isSingletonExistData = SingletonForCardFriend.getInstance().getListOfFriends().size() > 0;
    if (isSingletonExistData) {
        setUI();
    } 
}

private void setUI() {
    List<CardFriend> friends = SingletonForCardFriend.getInstance().getListOfFriends();
        contentFrameFree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        contentFrameRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rvFriends.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapterFriends = new AdapterFriends(friends, onCardListener);
        rvFriends.setAdapter(adapterFriends);
}
```

И метод который и обновляет каждый раз `Fragment`

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        fetchContacts();
    }
}
```

Если этот фрагмент сейчас виден юзеру то уставливается UI

Когда переключаюсь быстро раз до 10 то получаю вот такое сообщение

> W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by  android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{39437ee4 V.ED.... ......ID  201,111-303,168 #7f0e0139 app:id/bb_bottom_bar_title} during layout:  running second layout pass
>   09-11 17:38:38.081 556-556/com.fittingroom.newtimezone  I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much  work on its main thread.

В чем может быть ошибка? Может установка UI слишком ресурсозатратная? Адаптер и все такое я все подключаю в момент когда юзер попадает фрагмент виден...

Что делаю не так?

Если забыл что то добавить, говорите

**ПРАВКА**

Добавил видео

https://youtu.be/QgxKnTZkKdg

Стандартный синглтон

```
public class SingletonForCardFriend {
private static SingletonForCardFriend instance;
private List<CardFriend> listOfFriends;

private SingletonForCardFriend(){
    listOfFriends = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static SingletonForCardFriend getInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new SingletonForCardFriend();
    }
    return instance;
}

public List<CardFriend> getListOfFriends() {
    return listOfFriends;
}

public int setListOfFriends(List<CardFriend> listOfFriends) {
    this.listOfFriends = listOfFriends;
    return this.listOfFriends.size();
}

public int getSize(){
    return listOfFriends.size();
}
}
```

Таб адаптер

```
public class AdapterTabFriends extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int numberOfTabs;

public static final int FRIENDS_FRAGMENT_POSITION = 0;
public static final int INBOX_FRAGMENT_POSITION = 1;

private FragmentFriends friendsFragment;
private FragmentInbox inboxFragment;

public AdapterTabFriends(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.numberOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
    friendsFragment = new FragmentFriends();
    inboxFragment = new FragmentInbox();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case FRIENDS_FRAGMENT_POSITION:
            return friendsFragment;
        case INBOX_FRAGMENT_POSITION:
            return inboxFragment;
        default: return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numberOfTabs;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте не пересоздавать и переназначать адаптер с LayoutManager-ом, а лишь уведомлять его о изменении данных

```
private void setUI() {
    if(friends == null || friends.isEmpty()) {
        friends = SingletonForCardFriend.getInstance().getListOfFriends();
    }

    contentFrameFree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    contentFrameRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if(rvFriends.getLayoutManager() == null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rvFriends.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
    if(rvFriends.getAdapter() == null) {
        AdapterFriends adapter = new AdapterFriends(friends, onCardListener);
        adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        rvFriends.setAdapter(adapter);
        rvFriends.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
        rvFriends.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    } else {
        rvFriends.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

И переопределить в адаптере метод:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Не помогло( Я добавил видео в вопрос для общей картины

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, странно... Покажите что у вас внутри метода SingletonForCardFriend.getInstance().getListOfFriends()

Comment: Добавил. Не помню точно как называется эта реализация, но вроде ничего такого. Я думаю может проблема в реализации самих табов и их адаптера? Сейчас проверю

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, попробуйте ещё обновление ответа. Оно должно избавить, по идее, от лишних перерисовок на кои, вроде, у вас ругань в логах

Comment: Вы дописали в ответ переопределить метод, это я так понял в адаптере для `RecyclerView`? а зачем? И что значит обновление ответа? Или это оно и есть?

Comment: Я кстати проверил таб адаптер там все норм вроде... Добавил код в вопрос

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, да, это метод адаптера. В ответе я ещё добавил 4 строки при создании адаптера. Это должно помешать постоянной перерисовке

Comment: Ой)) Не туда добавил))

Comment: Да я добавил эти 4 строки, но не помогло... Так при чем что то загружает UI и даже если подождать какое то время и попробовать еще раз переключиться, то все равно висит... И с каждым разом больше и больше... Очень похоже на то что как то запускается какой то бесконесный цикл и с каждым переключением +1 и так до тех пор пока приложение не остонавливается... и потом только можно закрыть и заново запустить...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, а если вообще убрать вызов setUserVisibleHint? Т.е. закомментить его?

Comment: Нашел я в чем дело. Закоментил этот метод и начал раскрывать его сточка за строчкой. Я просто сократил код чтоб в вопросе не выкладывать кучу не нужного. Так вот там есть еще строчка которая показывает `BottomBar` когда юзер открывает нужный таб и видно этот метод когда делает `attach` этому `BottomBar` и вызывает такую реакцию. Сейчас покапаюсь в его библиотеке

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, если вы имеете в виду одну из сторонних реализаций `BottomSheet`, то у гугла есть уже своё решение, которое сейчас уже даже, вроде, нормально работает

Comment: Все спасибо!) Все починил) Суть была в том, что я каждый раз когда юзер уходил с таба удалял BottomBar а когда обратно возвращался опять создавал и прикреплял к активити... Нужно было просто скрывать и показывать, не нужно было постоянно создавать и удалять сам обьект... А пользуюсь я вот этой библиотекой https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Comment: Кстати Юрий вопрос не по теме, посоветуйте что нибудь по архитектуре приложения... Хочу научиться MVC ) Что делать?)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, рад был немного помочь) Спасибо за интересную либу, кстати) Я сам в MVC не особо силён, подсказать нечего)